# Ubuntu One Files (Android App) not removing deleted files

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

I have Ubuntu One Files installed on my Android phone. Photos are set to Auto-Upload which works fine - I see the photos on my windows machines as expected.

However, when I delete a photo from that folder using my Windows machine Ubuntu One Files does not remove the corresponding file from the Android phone.

Does the Android App not support two-way sync? Or have I overlooked something?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried syncing from Android.

Comment: From reading other posts I think I have found out the answer I am looking for: Ubuntu One has an option to Auto-Upload Photos from Android phones to a specified folder on Ubuntu One. This feature works fine - on my phone sdcard\dcim\100MEDIA replicates to Folder1 on Ubuntu One. When I delete a file from another device from Folder1 that does delete the file and it syncs just fine to all other Ubuntu One devices.

Comment: The catch is that Folder1 is not linked in anyway to sdcard\dcim\Media100. The Ubuntu One folder on Android is located at sdcard\u1\Folder1 - this folder1 and the photo location on Android phones are not linked to each other in anyway. Deleting a file in one location doesn't impact the copy in the other folder.

Comment: Apparently, Ubuntu One Files App for android is for viewing your content only. A little off topic to my questions but maybe useful to someone - according to this post dated April 30th: [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1940338) content put in sdcard\u1\Folder1 will not be sent to Ubuntu One.

Comment: You can add the above info as answer , that will help a Lot of Users in future , i would recommend you to do it. Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu One files app for Android does not do two way sync. Currently only photos are auto-uploaded. There are plans to support fuller sync functionality in the app with future updates. Announcements about this will be made on the Ubuntu One blog at http://voices.canonical.com/ubuntuone

Answer (score 2):

From reading other posts I have found the answer I am looking for:

Ubuntu One has an option to Auto-Upload Photos from Android phones to a specified folder on Ubuntu One. This feature works fine - on my phone sdcard\dcim\100MEDIA replicates to Folder1 on Ubuntu One. When I delete a file from another device from Folder1 it does infact delete the file from all other instances of Ubuntu One.

The catch is that Folder1 is not linked in anyway to sdcard\dcim\100MEDIA. The Ubuntu One folder on Android is located at sdcard\u1\Folder1. Deleting a file in one location doesn't impact the copy in the other folder.

Ubuntu One Files App for android is only good for viewing your content (and auto-uploading photographs)

A little off topic to my questions but maybe useful to someone - according to this post dated April 30th: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1940338 content put in sdcard\u1\Folder1 will not be sent to Ubuntu One. Confirms what Joshua Hoover says.

Until Ubuntu One Files supports two-way sync natively your best bet is Folder Sync Lite http://market.android.com/search?q=pname:dk.tacit.android.foldersync.lite - I installed this app, setup ubuntu one access (it also supports several other cloud storage providers) and set it up to do a two-way sync (with option to sync deletions) and it works like a champ. To avoid any confusion I disabled auto-upload of photos through Ubuntu One Files.